# Forward and backward slash php

Tags: php, laravel

I have an existing laravel project. I am running it on windows 10 machine. I am running the following command

```
cd c:/xampp/htdocs/demo/ (A file called index.php is there inside demo folder)

php -S localhost:8000
```

index.php file has contents as follows

```
<?php
 $uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
 $uri = urldecode($uri);
 $paths = require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/paths.php';
 $requested = $paths['public'].$uri;
 // This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
 // built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
 // application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
 if ($uri !== '/' and file_exists($requested))  
  {
    return false;
  }
  require_once $paths['public'].'/index.php';
?>
```

Now the problem is with **__DIR__** . When I am trying to print the path it is the mixing of both forward and backward slashes.

For example ($requested)

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\bootstrap/../public/
```

This don't let the app running and throws **internal server error(500)**

Many places in the project has **__DIR__** . I can't replace it in one place.

Can anybody help.

Comment: on windows, forward and backward slash mixing, in my experience,  works fine. it couldbe that the server does not have permission to enter the folder, also you could try using apache, instead of the php builtin server

Answer (score 0):

You can replace one of slash with another after getting mixed string

Example :

```
$requested = $paths['public'].$uri;
$requested = str_replace("\\", "/", $requested);
```

This will replace all `\` with `/`.

Comment: I have __DIR__ throughout the project

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `real_path()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Another solution would be not to hardcode neither slash or a backslash and use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead. It will output OS-specific path no matter where you run your code.

```
function file_build_path(...$segments) {
    return join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $segments);
}

file_build_path(__DIR__, 'public', 'index.php');
```